# MIKE Hydro Extended Validation Error: Q/h relation H-Neg must be increasing

Tags: hydrology

I am setting up a MIKE Hydro model for a basin. I am getting extended validation errors on MIKE Hydro

```
Weirs(267) extended validation: StructureName: Q/h relation H-Neg must be increasing
```

[image]

I tried calculating the Q/h relations for the weir again but the error persists. Also as shown in the figure above, H-Neg is increasing so I don't see why MIKE-Hydro is giving this extended validation error.

Comment: Manually adjusting the HPos and HNeg solved the problem temporarily but there might be a more convenient solution.